# JQuery Ajax format issue

Tags: ajax, amazon-web-services, rest, aws-lambda

My ajax query works like this:

```
$.ajax({
        type: "POST",
        url: "https://bljo2x1b0h.execute-api.eu-west-2.amazonaws.com/IncrementOne/competitions?competitionName=" + competitionNameVar 
    + "&competitionDescription=" + competitionDescriptionVar + "&competitionLocation=" + competitionLocationVar + "&competitionNumberOfProblems=" + competitionNumberOfProblemsVar 
    + "&competitionNumberOfZones=" + competitionNumberOfZonesVar + "&competitionDate=" + competitionDateVar + "&competitionUsername=" + localStorage.myUserName;,
        crossDomain: true,
        dataType: "text",
```

But not when I try to put the data into the data: parameter like this (or without the String()):

```
data: {
            "competitionName": String(competitionNameVar),
            "competitionDescription": String(competitionDescriptionVar),
            "competitionLocation": String(competitionLocationVar),
            "competitionNumberOfProblems": String(competitionNumberOfProblemsVar),
            "competitionNumberOfZones": String(competitionNumberOfZonesVar),
            "competitionDate": String(competitionDateVar),
            "competitionUsername": String(localStorage.myUserName),
        },
```

I cant see what the issue is. The crazy thing is that I have a get request set up in a similar way which works fine:

```
$.ajax({
        type: "GET",
        url: "https://bljo2x1b0h.execute-api.eu-west-2.amazonaws.com/IncrementOne/competitions",
        crossDomain: true,
        data: {
            "competitionsNameParameter": String(CompetitionName),
        },
```

Answer (score 0):

There is a difference between the query parameters and the request body. Depending on whether the `POST` API accepts query parameters or request body, you need to invoke that way. However, `POST` API should take the payload as the request body. And in that case, `data` attribute is needed and not the request parameters.

Consult the API provider and clarify this first. Accordingly, write the client code to consume the API.

Also, when you say it is not working can you share the results from the browser's network tab (the request URL, body, response header, message etc.)?